# Downloading files from urls listed in txt file without using wget

Tags: python, wget, downloading-website-files

Due to not being able to install wget library at my work I need a workaround for downloading files using URLs listed in a txt file. I have txt file called urls.txt which contains about a thousand of links each directing to the file that needs to be downloaded. So far I have something like this but unfortunately it isn't downloading any files although script is being executed.

```
import urllib.request

with open("urls.txt", "r") as file:
    linkList = file.readlines()
for link in linkList:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(link)
```

Answer (score 1):

> The second argument, if present, specifies the file location to copy to (if absent, the location will be a tempfile with a generated name)

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve).

You'll need to specify a second argument referring to a file path to which to download the file's contents to, like so:

```
...
for link in linkList:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, link.split('/')[-1])
```

As it stands, you're downloading into a temp file with a generated name.  I'm not 100% sure how you're meant to retrieve that name, so it's best to just specify the file path yourself.

Comment: Ok so my URL adress is something like /DocumentXML2XLSDownload.vm?firsttime=true&repengback=true&documentId=XXXXXX&xslFileName=rher2xml.xsl&outputFileName=XXXX_2017_06_25_4.xls and I want every file to be named after the last part "XXXX_2017_06_25_4.xls" and placed in the directory of the script. How should I proceed about that? I'm completely new to Python and still trying to figure out which phrase means what.

Comment: That's a separate question; you want to know how to parse a URL query string.  Google around for that, and if you have no luck, post a new question and poke me, and I'll write up another answer.

Comment: @Seidhe A quick and dirty way of getting that filename here would be similar to what @AdamBarnes used : `link.split('outputFileName=')[-1]` that will split the link in two parts around `"outputFileName="` so the last part (`[-1]`) will be your filename. A less hacky way would be indeed to dig into url parsing as mentionned.

Comment: Respectfully jadsq; that's not the correct way to do it.  One should use the `urllib.parse` module.  There are two functions in there specifically for this.

Comment: @AdamBarnes What is correct or not is very situational, if its a throwaway script you don't really have to go overkill ...

Comment: It's not overkill to use the methods provided in the standard library instead of rolling your own buggy implementation.  It's not as simple as you're assuming to parse URL parameters.  https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve  It's over 100 lines of code.